# Is possible includes REACT in MVC.net project?

Tags: c#, .net, reactjs, model-view-controller

The project is MVC .NET and the view have RAZOR and Javascript + Jquery.
I really would use react for create new components , I really say if i could combinate react, razor and javascript in the views cshtml.

Comment: React is a client side framework. MVC can serve files to the client. So sure, it can work. Of course modern JavaScript apps have a whole build process they go through and you'll have to figure out how to integrate it with MVC. Why don't you just do a React site and have it talk to ASP.NET Web API? Why do you even need MVC if you're using React?

Comment: Ty, because all the app is MVC, and is so hard migrate ALL to web api and views.

i am bored to use only javascript...

Comment: Have your controller in MVC return a view with your referenced JS assets, and an empty div with an id. Then use ReactDOM.render() to drop in your component.